# Transpose df.T is not working properly for my df, not sure where im going wrong

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

my initial data

```
Date        Copper     Zinc Aluminium US HRC                
2021-04-21  9448.0  2815.0  2377.0  1360.0
2021-04-27  9877.0  2929.0  2398.0  1360.0
%change     5.0     4.0     1.0      0.0
```

after I transpose using df.T
my output was,

```
            0         1         2
Copper     9448    9876     4.53853
Zinc       2815    2929     4.04973
Aluminium  2377    2398     0.874979
US HRC     1360     1360            0
Date    2021-04-21  2021-04-27  %change
```

But I want my final output to look like

```
        2021-04-21 2021-04-27   %change
Copper     9448     9876       4.53853
Zinc       2815     2929       4.04973
Aluminium  2377     2398       0.874979
US HRC     1360     1360            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dt.set_index('Date').T`

After transpose, row index will become column index.  So, if you want the column index show the value of Date column, you can make it row index before transpose.

### Demo

```
print(df)

         Date  Copper    Zinc  Aluminium  US_HRC
0  2021-04-21  9448.0  2815.0     2377.0  1360.0
1  2021-04-27  9877.0  2929.0     2398.0  1360.0
2     %change     5.0     4.0        1.0     0.0


print(df.set_index('Date').T)


Date       2021-04-21  2021-04-27  %change
Copper         9448.0      9877.0      5.0
Zinc           2815.0      2929.0      4.0
Aluminium      2377.0      2398.0      1.0
US_HRC         1360.0      1360.0      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
df=df.T
df
```